# Can I match any of possible route matches with react router dom 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom

I have 3 possible paths that can be under one path.
Is there any method that I can match all possible matches?

For example, the code as-is like

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const firstMatch = useMatch('/:appId/:firstKey');
  const secondMatch = useMatch('/:appId/:firstKey/:secondKey');
  const thirdMatch = useMatch('/:appId/:firstKey/:secondKey/:thirdKey');

  if (firstMatch == null && secondMatch == null && thirdMatch == null) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace={true} />;
  }
  const firstKey =
    (firstMatch?.params.firstKey) ||
    (secondMatch?.params.firstKey) ||
    (thirdMatch?.params.firstKey);

  return ....
```

pseudo-code should be..

```
const firstMatch = useMatch('/:appId/:firstKey?/:secondKey?/:thirdKey');
```

But I found that the question mark pattern is removed as of version 6.

Do I have better option?

Comment: Can you explain what the use case here is? What is the problem you are trying to solve for?

Comment: This works fine as-is. I was wondering if there is any better solution to optimize the code. I have 3 routes whose paths are like `/:pathA`, `/:pathA/:pathB`, `/:pathA/:pathB/:pathC`. Those routes are located in one `Routes` component. Each route has its corresponding element and the match params are used in the element.

Comment: Right, but understanding what you are trying to accomplish helps us understand what/where improvements can be made. Do each of those routes render the same `element` component? You can make the route paths with optional path segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional path params are available for the `Route` component's `path` prop, but for the time being they are incompatible with the `useMatch` hook and [`matchPath`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/utils/match-path) utility function. There is a filed github [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/9793) & [discussion](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/discussions/9862) regarding processing optional path segments in these hooks and utilities.

If you are looking for something a little more ***DRY*** than using three separate `useMatch` hooks then I'd recommend loading the paths you want to match into an array and iterating over each, checking the path with the `matchPath` utility function.

The logic may look similar to the following:

```
const patterns = [
  "/:appId/:firstKey/:secondKey/:thirdKey",
  "/:appId/:firstKey/:secondKey",
  "/:appId/:firstKey"
];

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  const match = patterns.reduce(
    (match, pattern) => (match ? match : matchPath(pattern, pathname)),
    null
  );

  if (!match) {
    return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
  }

  const { firstKey } = match.params;

  return (
    ....
  );
};
```

[image: Edit can-i-match-any-of-possible-route-matches-with-react-router-dom-6]

Since optional path segments work, it might just be easier to only match the routes you want to begin with.

Example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { firstKey } = useParams();

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

```
<Routes>
  ....
  <Route
    path="/:appId/:firstKey/:secondKey?/:thirdKey?" // <-- firstKey required
    element={<MyComponent />}
  />
  ....
  <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit can-i-match-any-of-possible-route-matches-with-react-router-dom-6 (forked)]